# Why does my text value not appear in matlab gui?

Tags: sql, matlab, textbox, matlab-guide

I've managed to retrieve 5 string values from my database whereby results = 'something1' 'something2' 'something3' 'something4' 'something5'. Now I want these values to display in my edit texts Matlab GUI. How do I do that? How to pass all values from *results = curs.Data;* to all 5 different *set(handles.edit1,'String');*?

```html
%Assign data to output variable
results = curs.Data;
display(results);

%Diplay in edit texts matlab gui
set(handles.edit1,'String'); 
set(handles.edit2,'String');
set(handles.edit3,'String');
set(handles.edit4,'String');
set(handles.edit5,'String');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `results` is a cell array then simply do:

```
set(handles.edit1,'String',results{1});
```

and repeat for each string. Or, if you wish, you can use `arrayfun`:

```
arrayfun(@(k) eval(['set(handles.edit' num2str(k) ',''String'',results{' num2str(k) '}); ']),1:5);
```